# Is there any event for cancelling order before or save order before?

Tags: magento

I need to refund the amount to customer if the order is cancelled. I want to process the refund initially after that based on the result (it's online refund system) I will cancel the order. So I'm looking for an event before cancelling the order or before save the order object. I tried with `sales_order_save_before` event. But it's not working. I think this event is not exists. Any ideas ..?

Comment: There's a nice event cheatsheet here: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Comment: Yeah I know. But I cannot find event which is related to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_cancel

To log all events do following change in Mage.php:

```
File: app/Mage.php
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log('Event: ' . $name); //not using Mage::log, as 
    //file_put_contents('/tmp/test.log','Dispatching '. $name. "\n",FILE_APPEND); //poor man's log
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

After adding above code, cancel an order and then check system.log. It will log all events fired before, during and after cancel order action. You will be able to find event suitable from you from this log.

Hope this helps.